# Using variables in onclick (keep old variable value even if changed later)

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I have a problem where I need to dynamically add onclick events in javascript buttons using variables that the user gives. **The problem**: These variables will change, but I dont want the onclick events to all change!!

I wrote up a mini example that mimics the setup I have (but obviously getting rid of unnecessary parts and therefore looks a bit silly).

NOTE: I tried to clone the variable using these:

```
1) clone = Object.assign({}, old);

2) clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(old);
```

Neither worked

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/samuel-solomon/pen/ExPqdpM

HTML:

```
<div id="1"></div>
```

CSS

```
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.blue{background-color: blue;}
.black{background-color: black;}
```

Javascript

```
btn1 = document.createElement('button');
var one_class = "button black";
btn1.className = one_class;
btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {btn1.className = one_class;})
add_first = document.getElementById('1');
add_first.appendChild(btn1).html;
one_class = "button blue"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to designate a specific value as the first parameter of the event handler. This will work as `one_class` is a string primitive.

```
btn1.addEventListener('click', function(cls, event) {
       btn1.className = cls;
}.bind(null, one_class));
```